# what equals app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" in Java?

Tags: java, android

In xml, I can use `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` as an attribute of a view. But now I want to create a view programmatically. What I know is like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

But how can I add `right` and `end` ?

Comment: params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.END;

Comment: @calvinfly You are right. can you please post your answer?

Comment: You should use either `right` or `end`, but not both. The point of `start` and `end` is to be right or left depending on your user's locale being left-to-right or right-to-left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may change to this

```
params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully answer:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton).getLayoutParams();
params.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.END;
findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonFlip).setLayoutParams(params);
```

This allow use another existing settings of LayoutParams and work fine for me.